# Google Adsense issue

Tags: javascript, wordpress, adsense

I am new to wordpress. I wanted a responsive google adsense to be displayed in my wordpress site. I got this responsive code from google ad sense

My wordpress site.[www.shoretemple.com](http://%20www.shoretemple.com)

```
<script async src="//"></script>
<!-- ShoreTemple_2015 -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-9979776236104288"
     data-ad-slot="3591025896"
     data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I have pasted this on the widget sidebar. It does not show anything. I waited for 3 days. Still nothing shows.. I tried inserting this code on a normal html page. It still didnt work too. But... when i paste this code :

```
<div class="banner300x250"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-9979776236104288";
/* ShoreTemple_MediumRectangle_3 */
google_ad_slot = "2865064305";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div>
```

This one works perfectly, But it is not responsive. Is there anything i am missing? If not, how to make it responsive.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Possible mistake ! ... Include this also in widget ( Any one if you have multiple )

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"> </script>`

Comment: give me the page link !

Comment: @DheerajNarayan .. I suggest you to try Google AdSense plugin .. Its really good.

Answer (score 0):

I found this awesome plugin called quick Ad sense. That solved my problem. Thank you